# Change Windows language settings programmatically in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I tried to set language from Mandarin to English using:

1. SystemParametersInfoA 
   API returns true, but the language of data collect from device manager is unchanged.

```
    DWORD hKLEnglUS = 0x00000409;
    if (SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, 0, &hKLEnglUS, SPIF_SENDCHANGE))   
        printf("Success!!\n");
    else
        printf("Error!!\n");
```

2. SetLocaleInfoA 
   Always occurs 1004 flag error by looking at GetLastError()

```
    LCID Locale = 0x409; //English - United States
    if (SetLocaleInfoA(Locale, LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, "0x409"))
        printf("Locale changed!\n");
    else {
        TCHAR m[] = _T("SetLocaleInfo");
        ErrorExit(m);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using SetThreadUILanguage API

Answer (score 0):

"ASCII string containing C source code-prefixed hexadecimal digits representing the numeric value of an LCID" is a *really* unusual format.  And it is not the correct one.

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-ilanguage) says

> Language identifier with a hexadecimal value. For example, English (United States) has the value 0409, which indicates 0x0409 hexadecimal, and is equivalent to 1033 decimal. The maximum number of characters allowed for this string is five, including a terminating null character.

So you need to pass `"0409"` with no `0x` prefix.

There's also a warning telling you not to use `LOCALE_ILANGUAGE` with `SetLocaleInfo`.

> Windows Vista and later: Use of this constant can cause GetLocaleInfo to return an invalid locale identifier. Your application should use the `LOCALE_SNAME` constant when calling this function.

The correct parameter with `LOCALE_SNAME` would be `"en-US"` as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c)

Comment: got same error when using: 
LCID Locale = 0x409; 
SetLocaleInfoA(Locale, LOCALE_SNAME, "0409"); 

"en-US" can't be the second parameter of the API (type error)