# SetLocaleInfoW always get 1004 flag error

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi

I want to set locale language to English, but I always get 1004 flag error when using the API. 
Please help me.. I got stuck in the problem for a long time

```
  LCID lcid = 0x409; //English - United States
  if (SetLocaleInfoW(lcid, LOCALE_SNAME, _T("en-US"))) 
      printf("Locale changed!\n");
  else
      wprintf(L"Error %d \n", GetLastError());
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply a system-wide configuration setting? You [previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68663617/1889329) seems to suggest, that you are looking for a way change your program's local settings only.

Comment: Not related (probably), but there is no good reason to ever mix explicit `A`/`W` APIs with `_T("")` strings.

Comment: Yes, my question was solved. The answer is in the previous question. But I wonder why the API always return False

Answer (score 1):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/locale-information-constants LOCALE_SNAME is not one of the items that can be set using SetLocaleInfo.

Comment: same error if the second argument is: LOCALE_ILANGUAGE, LOCALE_SLANGUAGE, LOCALE_SENGLANGUAGE

Comment: Those constants are also not in the list allowed for SetLocaleInfo